# Detecting keywords in input

Tags: python, chatbot

So I am completely new to Python. I started a week ago. I am writing a simple chatbot and have come to a point where I would like to ask an open-ended question, and if it picks up certain keywords in the input, it will print a certain response. I basically need an if command to be able to detect if a certain word is used. I hope there is some way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

To detect substrings you can use the `in` operator.
Example:

```
>>> "Hello" in "Hello World!"
True
>>> "Python" in "Hello World!"
False
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing this best solution would be to use regular expressions that way you can detect multiple keywords easily instead of having a dozen of if and elif under each other.
An example :

```
import re
regex_name = re.compile(r'name?$', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
regex_age = re.compile(r'age?$', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
my_input = input("Name : John")
if (regex_name.match(my_input)):
  print("The string Name was found")
elif( regex_age.math(my_input)):
  print("The string age was found")
else:
  print("Neither Name or Age were found")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
inpt = input("How are you?")
if "good" in inpt:
    print("Okay you are good")
else:
    print("what happend?")
```

The input() asks the user for input and the if statement checks for keywords of the users answer.

Comment: So I did it like this, and it keeps just defaulting to the if, and none of the elif or else works.

Comment: Yes this happens when good is inside the answer, but when you use another if isnstead of elif you can detect other keywords

Comment: So I should change all elifs to ifs? I did this and now it just prints every response.

Comment: When you just want one Keyword you use the elifs, otherwise when you want to get multiple use the if.  For e.g. the answer "I am very fine", when you use an if for fine and the elif for very, just the if would fire, because it wont get to the elif, but when you use an if for fine and an if for very, both will fire because they are independent of each other.